# Auto-complete with Pycharm without typing a letter or character first

Tags: autocomplete, ide, pycharm

Is there something I can press on the keyboard to get Pycharm to auto-complete without my first having to type a letter?

The purpose of this is so I can see all the possibilities as opposed to only the ones that start with the letter that I typed, or if I don't know what any of the possibilities are to begin with.

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: Make sure too that your 'Power Save Mode' is not checked or else the 'Completion' under the 'Code' menu will be grayed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can trigger different types of completion from the menu *Code → Completion* or using the corresponding keyboard shortcuts (depend on keymap):

Default completion shortcuts:

- Basic: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
- SmartType: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
- Class Name: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

[image: Completion types in PyCharm]